# rotation with easing in actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, rotation, easing

I cant figure this out at ALL, im new to actionscript so forgive me for my nievity.

This function snaps my wheel from 0 degree to 90 degrees. I would like it to rotate at a set speed (probably 5) and then stop at 90 degree intervals. im making a wheel with something written on each 1/4 of it. If at all possible i would also like it to ease or maybe even go past the 90 mark and then snap back to 90 degrees just to give it a bit more life but i know thats probably really advanced stuff. This is what i have so far:

```
    leftArrow_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bottomRotation);

    function bottomRotation (event:Event) :void {
bottomWheel_menu_mc.rotation += 90;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try greensock tween class its easy to you for stuff like this:
www.greensock.com

```
    import com.greensock.*;
    TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:65, y:117});   its easy and has samples : )
```